# Display all the stored procedures in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Is there any way to display all of the stored procedures in a database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
select * from sys.procedures
```

Answer (score 1):

here is other way:

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'P'
```